# EntityFramework connection string error in windows form designer

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am facing a problem in a windows forms application (.net 4.0) using entity framework 5.

I have a DbContext instance as a class field in a form like this:

```
protected MascoteAquariumEF model = new MascoteAquariumEF("name=MascoteAquariumEF");
```

here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MascoteAquariumEF" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/MascoteAquariumDBContext.csdl|res://*/MascoteAquariumDBContext.ssdl|res://*/MascoteAquariumDBContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=vm_visual_stdo\sqlexpress2008;initial catalog=MascoteAquarium;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And in the designer I am seeing this error: 
The form don't get really designed....but running the project its ok (no error)

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass name value only:

```
protected MascoteAquariumEF model = new MascoteAquariumEF("MascoteAquariumEF");
```

Also I think it's better to check if form in designer before instantiating your context:

```
protected MascoteAquariumEF model;

public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (DesignMode)
        return; // you don't need to create context

    model = new MascoteAquariumEF("MascoteAquariumEF");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @lazyberezovsky, this tip helped me to solve the problem!